# What Data Structure would you use for a Curriculum of a Department in a University?

Tags: c#

For my homework, I'm implementing a course registration system for a university and I implemented a simple class for Curriculum with list of semesters and other properties like name of the department, total credits etc.

But I'm wondering if I can inherit this class from a Graph Data Structure with Edges and vertices.

Anybody done similar things before?

My current design is something like this:

```
public class Curriculum
{
    public string NameOfDepartment { get; set; }
    public List<Semester> Semesters { get; set; }

    public bool IsProgramDesigned { get; set; }

    public Curriculum()
    {
        IsProgramDesigned = false;
    }

    // 
    public string AddSemester(Semester semester)
    {
```

Comment: Why do you want to inherit from a graph data structure?

Comment: that would lead me to apply graph algorithms later on.. just wondering, i want to design it with something advanced. I hope you will not ask me why would I want graph algorithms

Comment: What kind of graph alogrithms do you need to apply to this structure?

Comment: I'm just trying to practice. There are relations between courses in semesters. Some of them are prerequisites of others, some of them are electives. I've already finished and submit my project but I thought this would be a good practice for Graph Algorithm. Course registration, transcript staff, limitation of credits of courses in semesters etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an enterprise architect I would absolutely not use a graph structure for this data. This data is a list and nothing more.

For a problem similar to this, the only reason I would ever consider using a graph structure would be to potentially create the relationship of course requirements and prerequisites.

This way you could then use the graph algorithm to determine if it is valid for a student to register for a class by making sure it is a valid addition to the tree. Same for removing classes, it could be validated to make sure you aren't dropping a class and staying enrolled in the lab for the class example.

Now if I was going to actually implement this. I would still have an overall list of classes that have a Key to the vertex in the graph representation. One thing to keep in mind is that graph algorithms are about the biggest heavy hitter you can throw at a database so minimize the amount of work done to pull the graph out is always key. Depending on the size and scope, I would also evaluate if I could store entire graphs in a serialized form or to use a document database for the same reason.

Which in this example would be the most likely route I would take. I would store the entire object of prerequisites co-requisites and so on right inline with my course object. Since the graph is a set it and done event there's no need to do an actual graph traversal and you're better off storing the pre-calculated graph.

Comment: thank you for the input. In my solution I'm saving Specific Curriculum for a department in a db table and save it to another table named studentscurriculums which has a many to many relationship with the student and curriculum objects when there is student registration. The admin is able to create a new curriculum as well. But I will have to deal with course registration with some extra functions with this way. What I was wondering is that this curriculum class could be designed in a better way by using a Graph or Set and I was hoping someone who has already dealed before and share it here.

Comment: for example I have a CheckPrerequisites( List<Course> , Semester ) method which has 3 nested loops inside. I'm checking each prerequisite course if it's taken and graded before, before registering a course.. I have to deal with some other restrictions like special course count. If a student takes at least 4 of those courses, he will be certificated as a xx special or etc..

Comment: for homework that's ok but just thinking about a better way to decrease the cost of memory..

Comment: @Kubi in the real world memory and CPU are almost after thoughts, it's disks that are almost always the bottle necks. This generally means always being concerned about minimizing database usage, and sensibly maximizing your memory use. Now as you noticed in solving the course prerequests validation is a strange beast for iteration and could indeed by aided by using a graph algorithm. My key point was to always be thinking about what you're doing and where things are going. It wouldn't make sense to make your course entirely depeneden to the graph structure. Only the *relationships* for prereqs

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can inherit this class from a Graph data structure. You can make it a subclass of anything you want (except for a sealed class). The question of whether or not it is a wise design is entirely dependant on what you want to do. I assume you know how, so comment if you need an example of how to implement inheritance.

IF you are wanting to write your own graphing algorithms, why not just model it yourself? It would probably be a fun exercise.

Comment: I've already code first developed an entity framework application and submitted my project. I know how to inherit and my c# is pretty enough. Here I'm looking for a design. Do you know any graph class implemented in c# so that I can inherit? I had an eye on codeplex.

Comment: @Kubi what sort of graphing are you wanting to do? A table layout for data, a bar graph, pie charts, so on...

Comment: @Kubi, oh you mean an actual graph. I would just model that myself, but that is just me--especially if this is homework. Go to the library and grab a good book on Euler's graph theory and start building some objects to model it. Then after you have modeled most of Euler's stuff, move on to more complex operations using Euler as you base.